# Smallest available integer in MySql with EF5

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-5

I recently came into a situation where I need to get the smallest available integer in one of my table.

I've the following simple SQL query

```
SELECT MIN(t1.system + 1) AS nextSystem 
FROM mytable t1
   LEFT JOIN mytablet2
       ON t1.system  + 1 = t2.system
WHERE t2.system  IS NULL
```

But I cannot use it because

1. I've to use LINQ to SQL (With EF 5)
2. Uniqueness to be verified against two different column in same table (column names : **system** & **user**

So, in simple words, 
I need to get the smallest integer is not present in both columns

Answer (score 0):

One option to make it work would be to use the `SqlQuery` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

You can build the raw SQL and execute it without using LINQ. Here is an example using T-SQL:

```
 using (var ctx = new Entities())
{
    var query =
        ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
            "SELECT TOP 1 t1.Id+1 FROM MyEntities t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyEntities t2 WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id + 1) ORDER BY t1.Id");

    var res = query.First();
}
```

Alternatively if you don't like embedding SQL in the data-layer you can execute a store procedure using the SqlQuery method.